# How to disable "three single comment-markers" in visual studio express 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

In [Auto generate function documentation in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429452/auto-generate-function-documentation-in-visual-studio) Michael Paulukonis explains how to **create** comment templates by typing in "three single comment-markers". It works.

But I hate it. How can I **stop** Studio from creating those templates whenever I type a row of slashes? I can type two, and copy them to create four or insert a blank and later remove it, but arrrgh!

I tried to follow the link to [tips on editing VS templates.](http://blog.davebouwman.com/index.php/2007/06/streamline-coding-with-visual-studio-templates/) but that leads to nothing. No templates here on any Studio version (2010, 2012xp, 2013xp) on my machine..

And of course I tried to find it under the studio options, but couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools...Options...Text Editor...C#...Advanced. Uncheck: "Generate XML documentation comments for ///"