# Auto generate all inline XML documentation for a C# project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have a project with over 100 C# classes and want to generate the documentation for every variable, property and method. In the Visual Studio macOS IDE you can do this for 1 method at a time with `///` , but this is monkey work to do this for all classes.

Is there a possibility to automate this in Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio for Mac? If not, is there an IDE where I can do this?

I don't want a program that bundles the documentation (like Doxygen), I want something that adds the inline documentation, I will add the documentation myself (or edit the autogenerated documentation).

Comment: So you need somethig that would generate empty summary tags for you?

Comment: GhostDoc could do the trick: http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx However, it can only generate comments derived from the information in the code. That makes it pretty usesless if you don't upgrade it with useful information

Comment: @MaLiN2223 Visual studio for mac does not generate empty tags. It gives a generated summary and a summary of every paramater of your method.

Comment: Did you try to search for similar problems? Check for answers in e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/429452/1997232).

Comment: The problem with auto-generating the documentation comments is it's then difficult to keep track of which ones are currently useless (just auto-generated) vs the ones that are useful (have real documentation attached). Your one chance to know this for sure is to *not* auto-generate them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get your point. You have to document all types and members anyway, so your overhead is typing `///` per documented entity. Generated documentation comments, as Damien notes, are utterly useless, so you'd have to go over each and every documentation comment anyway. Three keystrokes is fairly negligible compared to the effort of actually _writing_ documentation, I think. But if you're just after generating an empty summary for everything, then that's probably half an hour of effort to do with Roslyn.

Comment: How to generate todo list in xamarin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) or [SandCastle](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10526). Sandcastle is a standalone app that will run over the source in your project folder, while Ghostdoc is a plugin for Visual Studio.

Sadly, neither work on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) for C# documentation, it works for Xamarin too.

Comment: From the Question: "I don't want a program that bundles the documentation (like Doxygen),..."

Comment: ok sorry, I suggest it because I used it and I found it perfect.

Comment: How to generate todo list in xamarin?