# How do we Generate an ITokenBuilder class/interface in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do we generate the ITokenBuilder class/interface in C# that has all the necessary tags and stuff like in the code snippet below:

```
 /// <summary>
 ///  Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Token"/> class.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="builder">Token builder</param>
 protected Token(ITokenBuilder builder)
 {
     Lexeme = builder.Lexeme;
     LeftTrivia = builder.LeftTrivia;
     RightTrivia = builder.RightTrivia;
 }
```

Do I need to manually type in the `/// <summary>` stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by "the necessary tags"? They're documentation snippets.

Comment: What I am trying to say is: Do I have to create an empty class/interface and then manually type in

`/// <summary>
 ///  Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Token"/> class.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="builder">Token builder</param>
`

Comment: You can create a template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: Watch this video for advanced templates https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uYN3mDFP-o

Comment: I will try to create the template then I will let you know how it goes

Comment: Type [///](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34587325/1997232) and use [other tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags) to add documentation to `public` members. I wouldn't bother with documenting anything else (e.g. `protected`, unless it's a library and implementing abstract members is required), just give them good self-explanatory names.

Comment: So I added the `///` and it worked.  It auto filled the summary and params tags for me. 

Thanks